# For what values is CORRECT used for Input or Ouput values?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I am learning the concept of Unit testing and came across below technique.

> Right: Are the results right?
>
> B: Are all the Boundary conditions **CORRECT**?
>
> I: Can we check inverse relationships?
>
> C: Can we cross-check results using other means?
>
> E: Can we force error conditions to happen?
>
> P: Are performance characteristics within bounds?

I am confused with the below area:

> B: Are all the boundary conditions **CORRECT**?

Q) What does CORRECT test, input or the output values?

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you are asking. What does B: I: ... stand for. Please try to rephrase.

Comment: @GhostCat I know What B stands for (it is checking boundary conditions check). What I would like to know is inside that, why is CORRECT used? Is it for Input values or output Values

Answer (score 1):

B) (http://media.pragprog.com/titles/utj/StandaloneSummary.pdf)

- Conformance — Does the value conform to an expected format?
- Ordering — Is the set of values ordered or unordered as appropriate?
- Range — Is the value within reasonable minimum and maximum values?
- Reference — Does the code reference anything external that isn’t
  under direct control of the code itself?
- Existence — Does the value exist? (e.g., is non-null, non-zero,
  present in a set, etc.)
- Cardinality — Are there exactly enough values?
- Time (absolute and relative) — Is everything happening in order? At
  the right time? In time?

Comment: I am confused that what type of parameters to test using the CORRECT?

Comment: Past some code, and it will be easier to answer your question. Typically params passed in to a method...

Comment: There is no code. This is a general question. For Knowledge